# Reading and writing size_t to a binary file

Tags: c++

Disclaimer: it's just another task for beginner so I'm good with the fact that on different compilers and on different architectures I may get different (incompatible) binaries as a result. So it's ok that it will only work only on this particular machine.

I'm writing and reading `size_t` from a binary file. Writing looks like:

```
std::string result;
result.append((char *)&block_size_, sizeof(block_size_));
```

and soon after that `result` is written to a file.

But when I read it in a same way:

```
map_binary.copy((char *)&block_size_, sizeof(block_size_), offset);
```

I get a warning

```
warning C4996: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::copy': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring(1777) : see declaration of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::copy'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
```

I cannot get why this code is unsafe and looking for a solution other than pretending there is no issues at all (using the `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`).

So, what am I missing?

PS: right now I'm learning C++ using only standard library, so solutions that use `boost` or something else are unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything. VC++ is very keen to warn you if you copy anything to a pointer. In this case there is no guarantee that you will get the size of destination correct. After all you might write something like this `map_binary.copy((char *)&block_size_, 4, offset);` and then find your code fails with a 64-bit compiler.

If you're happy with your ability to avoid this kind of error then disable or ignore the warning.

Comment: So, uhm, `std::string::copy()` **always** throws such a warning (when we compile it using VC++)?

Comment: I think so, many standard C and C++ functions do with this compiler.

Comment: "In this case there is no guarantee that you will get the size of destination correct" --- does that mean that it just warns me that I may corrupt some data in memory in case if I read *more* bytes than I had to?

Comment: Write more bytes I think. You are writing to &block_size.

Comment: yep, that's what I meant (just couldn't phrase it in proper english)

Comment: OK, well MS are just being paranoid. I guess because they've been burned so many times with buffer overflows in their own code.